# Label: Entering long text onto screen

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy, spyder, kivy-language

I am trying to get a really long text with numbered points and paragraphs onto the a screen within my app using the `kivy` library for python. However, I haven't been successful in this because I am using the `Label` property which only allows one line of code. If I could get some pointers on what I should implement within my code, that would be great! I was thinking of placing the long text into a text file and reading it from there but am not too sure how to. The place I want to enter a long text within the app is `"What can I do" -> "How to prevent a heart attack"`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string("""
<Bump@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.8,0.4 
    background_color: 1,0,0,1

<Back@Button>: 
    text: 'back'
    pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0.9}
    size_hint: 0.2,0.1

<menu>:

    Bump:
        text: "What can I do?"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'info'
        on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
    Label:
        text: "Remity Biotechnologies"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.95}

<info>:
    Bump:
        text: "How to prevent a heart attack?"
        size_hint:0.8,0.15
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.15}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'info2'
        on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
    Back:
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
<info2>
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        bar_width: 4
        Label:                            #PROBLEM LOCATED HERE
            text: "THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT A LONG TEXT"
            font_size: 90
            size_hint_x: 1.0               
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]


    Back:
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'info'
        on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'       


""")     
class confirm(Popup):
    pass

class menu(Screen):
    def update(self,dt):
        pass

class info(Screen):
    def update(self,dt):
        pass

class info2(Screen):
    def update(self,dt):
        pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):  
    def update(self,dt):
        self.current_screen.update(dt)

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(menu(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(info(name='info'))
sm.add_widget(info2(name='info2'))


class SimpleKivy4(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy4().run()
```

The text I would like to enter is...

```
long_text =\

"""1)   Be more physically active
Consult with your doctor on the type of exercise you can do and attempt to be consistent with your work outs, with 150 minutes of physical activity every week. Some simple exercises we can recommend are brisk walking, cycling, squats, tow and chair stands, and etc. 
2)  Quit smoking
Smoking is the leading cause of preventable death. It damages the artery walls which increases the chances of atrial fibrillation, strokes and even cancer. Put it out before it puts you out. 
3)  Don’t drink a lot of alcohol
Drinking alcohol raises your blood pressure and severely damages the cardiovascular system. Men should bring no more than 2 drinks a day and women only one. One drink represents 
-One 12-ounce can or bottle of regular beer, ale, or wine cooler
-One 8- or 9-ounce can or bottle of malt liquor
-One 5-ounce glass of red or white wine
-One 1.5-ounce shot glass of distilled spirits like gin, rum, tequila, vodka, or whiskey

4)  Healthy diet
Start eating foods that are low in trans and saturated fats, added sugars and salt. Eat more fruits, vegetables, whole grains, and highly fibrous foods. You should aim for a healthy weight by having smaller portion sizes. 
5)  Manage stress
Stress itself can increase blood pressure and blood clots which increases the chances of heart related problems. Learn to manage your stress levels by doing meditation or physical activities. 
"""
```

Comment: Put newlines (`\n`) in the long text, possibly?

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Label:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Source / blog post about it: https://blog.kivy.org/2014/07/wrapping-text-in-kivys-label/

Answer (score 0):

Your existing codes for Label can handle long text. You can place the long text in the class if it doesn't change very often.

## Python Script

Declare the long_text in class info2:

### py - Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...
class info2(Screen):
    long_text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(info2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.long_text = """
        1)   Be more physically active
        Consult with your doctor on the type of exercise you can do and attempt to be consistent with your work outs, with 150 minutes of physical activity every week. Some simple exercises we can recommend are brisk walking, cycling, squats, tow and chair stands, and etc. 
        2)  Quit smoking
        Smoking is the leading cause of preventable death. It damages the artery walls which increases the chances of atrial fibrillation, strokes and even cancer. Put it out before it puts you out. 
        3)  Don’t drink a lot of alcohol
        Drinking alcohol raises your blood pressure and severely damages the cardiovascular system. Men should bring no more than 2 drinks a day and women only one. One drink represents 
        -One 12-ounce can or bottle of regular beer, ale, or wine cooler
        -One 8- or 9-ounce can or bottle of malt liquor
        -One 5-ounce glass of red or white wine
        -One 1.5-ounce shot glass of distilled spirits like gin, rum, tequila, vodka, or whiskey

        4)  Healthy diet
        Start eating foods that are low in trans and saturated fats, added sugars and salt. Eat more fruits, vegetables, whole grains, and highly fibrous foods. You should aim for a healthy weight by having smaller portion sizes. 
        5)  Manage stress
        Stress itself can increase blood pressure and blood clots which increases the chances of heart related problems. Learn to manage your stress levels by doing meditation or physical activities. 
        """
```

## kv file

- Always change the ScreenManager transition direction first before switching the screen.
- Replace `text: "THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT A LONG TEXT"` with `text: root.long_text`

### kv - Snippets

```
    on_press: 
        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        root.manager.current = 'info'
    ...

Label:
    text: root.long_text
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<Bump@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.8,0.4 
    background_color: 1,0,0,1

<Back@Button>: 
    text: 'back'
    pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0.9}
    size_hint: 0.2,0.1

<menu>:

    Bump:
        text: "What can I do?"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'info'
    Label:
        text: "Remity Biotechnologies"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.95}

<info>:
    Bump:
        text: "How to prevent a heart attack?"
        size_hint:0.8,0.15
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.15}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'info2'
    Back:
        on_press: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
<info2>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        bar_width: 4

        Label:
            text: root.long_text
            font_size: 90
            size_hint_x: 1.0               
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

    Back:
        on_press: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'       
            root.manager.current = 'info'


""")


class confirm(Popup):
    pass


class menu(Screen):
    def update(self, dt):
        pass


class info(Screen):
    def update(self, dt):
        pass


class info2(Screen):
    long_text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(info2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.long_text = """
        1)   Be more physically active
        Consult with your doctor on the type of exercise you can do and attempt to be consistent with your work outs, with 150 minutes of physical activity every week. Some simple exercises we can recommend are brisk walking, cycling, squats, tow and chair stands, and etc. 
        2)  Quit smoking
        Smoking is the leading cause of preventable death. It damages the artery walls which increases the chances of atrial fibrillation, strokes and even cancer. Put it out before it puts you out. 
        3)  Don’t drink a lot of alcohol
        Drinking alcohol raises your blood pressure and severely damages the cardiovascular system. Men should bring no more than 2 drinks a day and women only one. One drink represents 
        -One 12-ounce can or bottle of regular beer, ale, or wine cooler
        -One 8- or 9-ounce can or bottle of malt liquor
        -One 5-ounce glass of red or white wine
        -One 1.5-ounce shot glass of distilled spirits like gin, rum, tequila, vodka, or whiskey

        4)  Healthy diet
        Start eating foods that are low in trans and saturated fats, added sugars and salt. Eat more fruits, vegetables, whole grains, and highly fibrous foods. You should aim for a healthy weight by having smaller portion sizes. 
        5)  Manage stress
        Stress itself can increase blood pressure and blood clots which increases the chances of heart related problems. Learn to manage your stress levels by doing meditation or physical activities. 
        """

    def update(self, dt):
        pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def update(self, dt):
        self.current_screen.update(dt)


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(menu(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(info(name='info'))
sm.add_widget(info2(name='info2'))


class SimpleKivy4(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy4().run()
```

## Output

[image: App Startup]
[image: Scrolled to point 2]
[image: Scrolled to bottom of long text]